# Apache Tomcat not working in every web browser installed in Windows7 32Bit

Tags: apache, jsp, windows-7, tomcat

I'm working on a web application in JSP and my web container is Apache Tomcat 7.0.2 (Its portable cross-platform version). As I've made extensive use of HTML5-CSS3 and my target browser is Google Chrome, I'm able to run the the Apache server only in Opera web browser, neither of the remaining installed browser run it.

Here's the steps I have followed to start the server in my Windows 7 machine.

-Installed the Apache Tomcat service in Windows from apache-tomcat-7.0.2/bin/service.bat

-Started the service with tomcat7w.exe

-As my default port is 8080, I open 'http://localhost:8080/' in various web browsers, and I could see Apache Server Homepage with same address only in Opera Web Browser (11.01), neither of other browsers installed can open it (Chrome 9, Firefox 4 Beta 11 or IE8) and show standard page not found message.

-I also tried other port numbers, but none of them worked.

What can I do to make Apache run in every browser installed in my computer?

I have my computer dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10, and in Ubuntu, every web browser installed can run Apache once I start it, but same is not working in Windows.

Update:

I have also tried apache's windows-only installer of version 7.0.8 and changed the port number during installation, but still I can't run it on any other browser expect for Opera...

Any help will be appreciated............
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your hosts file under C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to make sure that the entry for

`127.0.0.1    localhost`

is intact. Also see that if you are behind a proxy server, the settings allow for localhost to be bypassed.

Comment: Yes, hosts file had issue and localhost was not marked by 127.0.0.1, though my issue just solved right now, I was playing with addresses and fortunately got it done by trying http://127.0.0.1:8080/, and apache showed of on every browser installed. Anyway, thanks for help... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Congo!! finally got it done, instead of localhost, it works with 127.0.0.1 (which is localhost anyway)
So those who are facing similar issues, as suggested by [adarshr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343955/adarshr), go through your hosts file to see if localhost is correctly addressed to 127.0.0.1, or if you don't want to edit that file, you can still get it done by simply using http://127.0.0.1:8080/ instead of http://localhost:8080/. Please be sure about port number you are using, in my case it was 8080, it might vary depending on how you've configured.

Comment: Thanks for the answer comment.. If every questioner follows like this, It would be good.